# Validate string against regex

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to validate file paths with a regular expression. So far I've come up with this:

```
preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9\.\/\\\\]/', $string);
```

so it will return 1 if the string has any other characters than A-Z, a-z, 0-9, dot, \ and /

How can I make it so it also returns 1 if there are more than two dots in the string, or if the dot is at the end of the string?

And how can I allow `:` but only if it's present as the 2nd character and followed by `\` or `/`. For example `c:\file` should be valid

Comment: Just try to access the file and catch the error. Don't bother validating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the first two requirements:

```
preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9\.\/\\\\]|\..*\.|\.$/', $string);
```

The `\..*\.` will match if there are more than two dots. `\.$` will match if there is a dot at the end.  By separating each of these portions (including your original regex) with a `|` it will make it so the regex will match any one of the expressions (this is called alternation).

The last requirement is a little tricky, since if I understand correctly you need this to return 1 if there is a `:`, unless the only colon is the second character and it is followed by a `\` or `/`.  The following regex (as a PHP string) should do that:

```
'/:(?!(?<=^[a-zA-Z]:)[\/\\\\])/'
```

Or combined with the other regex (note that we also have to add `:` to the first character class):

```
preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9\.\/\\\\:]|\..*\.|\.$|:(?!(?<=^[a-zA-Z]:)[\/\\\\])/', $string);
```

Here is the explanation for that last piece:

```
:                  # match a ':'
(?!                # but fail if the following regex matches (negative lookahead)
   (?<=^[a-zA-Z]:)   # the ':' was the second character in the string
   [\/\\\\]          # the next character is a '/' or '\'
)                  # end lookahead
```

Comment: thanks! last part doesn't seem to work though. Could I negate this expression: `^[A-Za-z]:[\.\/\\\\]` ? So if this doesn't match it should fail

Comment: @Alex See my edit, the issue with the old version was that `:` needs to be added to the character class from your original regex or every `:` will cause the regex to match.  `:(?!(?<=^[a-zA-Z]:)[\/\\\\])` is the negation of the regex from you comment (except for the `.`, do you really want `C:.test` to be valid?).

Comment: Nope, but I added the dot in the list by mistake :) thanks again :P

Answer (score 1):

If this is for files on your server, this is what [realpath](https://www.php.net/realpath) is for. It will resolve references to `.` and `..` and check if the file exists at that path. If the file doesn't exist it returns false, if it does exist it returns the new path.